# Strange Behaviour of Linkbutton

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Whenever I am clicking on Linkbutton I am getting error that in Screen shot below.

[image]

Note: I Have not used any update panel with page.

> HTML

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSend" runat="server" CssClass="button submitButton" ValidationGroup="SurveyQuestion" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="SendQuestion_Click"></asp:LinkButton> <span>Submit</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

Any one can help me with this?

Comment: Please post your code, not picture of your code ... Sorry but this is post for ants.

Comment: Can you post a little html, at least the linkbutton part

Comment: @mybirthname open the image in a new tab and click on it.

Comment: @cracker - Your complete code(mark-up & JS), not just button control.

Comment: As far as I can see, the code that sets `theForm` to romansForm  sets it to undefined. Can you please put a breakpoint on the code above the `__doPostBack` function and see if `theForm` is different than `undefined`?

Comment: But this is anyways straightforward. Your `theForm` variable gets set to `undefined` before it's referenced inside the `__doPostBack` function.

Comment: @MikeJM yes it is so what I need to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see on the picture, you're trying to access a property on `theForm` which is declared inside another function that is unknown to the the `__doPostBack` function. One thing you can do is to take that local variable out of the function and make it global, so that it's available to any function.

To illustrate it better, this is what you're doing:

```
function someFunctionAbove__doPostBack()
{
   var theForm=document.forms["romansForm"];
   if(!theForm)
       theForm=documents.romansForm;
}

function __doPostBack(eventTarget,eventArgument)
{
   if(!theForm.onsubmit)//bla blaa
}
```

As you can see, `__doPostBack` function has no clue about the `theForm` variable. Just change it to this:

```
    var theForm=null;
    function someFunctionAbove__doPostBack()
    {
      theForm=document.forms["romansForm"];
      if(!theForm)
         theForm=documents.romansForm;
     }
```